# Map a function which takes three parameters on to a vector of three-element vectors in Clojure

Tags: function, clojure

I have a function:

```
(defn myfunc [x y z] ....does something interesting here )
```

I have a vector of data groups:

```
(def mydata [[:a1 :b1 :c1] [:a2 :b2 :c2] [:a3 :b3 :c3]])
```

I want to call myfunc three times with each such as:

```
(myfunc :a1 :b1 :c1)
(myfunc :a2 :b2 :c2)
(myfunc :a3 :b3 :c3)
```

I have a vague understanding this is going to include mapping and deconstructing? Other than that I am stuck..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First important point to grasp is that

```
(my-func :a1 :b1 :c1)
```

is ideologically equal to

```
(apply my-func [:a1 :b1 :c1])
```

After you're ok with it, it's easy to implement what you need using combination of [`map`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map), [`partial`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partial) and [`apply`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/apply):

```
(def mydata [[:a1 :b1 :c1] [:a2 :b2 :c2] [:a3 :b3 :c3]])

(map (partial apply my-func) mydata)
```